# Extract coefficients from a list of regression results in R

Tags: r, linear-regression

I have created vectors out of data frame data and stored them in a list. Take this example:

```
# Simulation data
vec2 <- c(2:20)
vec3 <- c(21:39)
vec4 <- c(31:49)
vec5 <- c(2:20)
vec6 <- c(2:20)
vec7 <- c(21:39)
vec8 <- c(31:49)
vec9 <- c(21:39)
vec10 <- c(31:49)
# Make simulated df to replicate something close to what I have
df <- data.frame(vec2,vec3,vec4,vec5,vec6,vec7,vec8,vec9,vec10)
```

So we have a dummy df. Next, I will extract the rows that I need for the regression (y):

```
    # Extract data from df and place in a list 
var <- list()
for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
  var[i] <- list(c(df$vec2[i],
                   df$vec3[i],
                   df$vec4[i],
                   df$vec5[i],
                   df$vec6[i],
                   df$vec7[i],
                   df$vec8[i],
                   df$vec9[i],
                   df$vec10[i]))
}

# Create x regression variable input 
log.lags <- c(2:10)
```

Ok so now we should have a list, that is this long:

> length(var)
>   [1] 19

With both the y,x regression variables the same length long:

```
> length(var[[1]])
[1] 9

> length(log.lags)
[1] 9
```

Now I want to run a regression over var list as the y independent variable and the log.logs as x, independent.

```
I try this with the following: 
#Initialize list
results<-vector("list", length(var)) 
# Run regression
for(i in 1:length(df)){
  results[[i]]<-lm(log(var[[i]])~log(log.lags), data = var)
}
```

This works... how can I then extract the coefficients from the results list?

Ok figured it out:

```
results<-vector("list", length(var)) 
coef<-vector("list", length(var)) 
for(i in 1:length(df)){
  results[[i]]<-lm(log(var[[i]])~log(log.lags), data = var)
  coef[[i]]<- coef(results[[i]])[2]
}
```

Comment: Maybe change `1:length(df)` to `1 : nrow(df)`. Also, `variance` same as `var`?

Comment: Best practice is to avoid using R command names as user-defined variable names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about this?

```
res <- lapply(var, function(x) lm(log(x)~log(log.lags)))
coefs <- lapply(res, function(x) coef(x)[2])
```

Comment: give me a lm.fit answer (its faster) lm.fit with log(y)~log(x) and il accept, im close now...

Comment: lm.fit needs a matrix input... and my input is a list. lm is just very very slow!!

Comment: You can do the following.. but, I don't think it will be faster. ` res2 <- lapply(var, function(x) lm.fit(log(as.matrix(x)), log(log.lags)))`